# Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under "...", but the tool couldn't find it

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, visual-studio-code, gradle

**When trying to debug my Flutter app on Android emulator I am getting the above mentioned error.**

I've tried and tested many solutions like **specifying flavor name** in build gradle file, running commands like **flutter run --flavor dev lib/main_dev.dart**, but still the same error comes up and the app does not run neither on the emulator nor on the device.

This is my **app/build.gradle** file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')

if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk 
in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 33


defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.ritemystory.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 16
    versionName "1.4.1"

    multiDexEnabled true
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? 
file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.ritemystory.app.dev"
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "RiteMyStory Dev"
    }
    staging{
        dimension "default"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "default"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "RiteMyStory"
         }
       }
    }

 flutter {
source '../..'
 }

dependencies {
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

This is my **android/build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.1'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Provide the updated code if any. Let me know if any code file is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your command. The command should be:

```
flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

or

```
flutter run --flavor dev --target lib/main_dev.dart
```

You didn't exactly specify the target.

Comment: The command that I mentioned in my question works fine but the issue is that the app is not running on the emulator neither on the device. The commands provided by you says Target file " " not found.

Comment: Check well. The command you gave, you did not specify target. You are missing the --target or -t flag as i mentioned in my response.

I have seen this happen but in release mode, where you do flutter build and not specify the target and flavour. You get the error ```It's likely that this file was generated under "...", but the tool couldn't find it``` similar to what you have.

I am guessing its similar for debug mode.

Comment: On using this command flutter run -t lib/main.dart --flavor dev  apk is build successfully. But still the same issue comes up when i try to run without debugging.  I want that it should run on the emulator .